# Building multi-stage docker image with a distroless base image results in "no such file or directory" error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, virtualenv, docker-multi-stage-build, distroless

I am making a multi-stage docker image that uses Python's official image for the builder image and Google's distroless image as the base for the runner image. Before this, i tested the multi-stage build from Python's official image for both the builder and runner image as follows.

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim AS builder-image

# avoid stuck build due to user prompt
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# create and activate virtual environment
# using final folder name to avoid path issues with packages
RUN python3.11 -m venv /home/myuser/venv
ENV PATH="/home/myuser/venv/bin:$PATH"

# install requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir wheel
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.11.4-slim AS runner-image

RUN useradd botuser

COPY /app /app
RUN chmod 755 /app && mkdir /files && chmod 744 /files
USER botuser
WORKDIR /tmp
ENV APP_TMP_DATA=/tmp

# activate virtual environment
COPY --from=builder-image /home/myuser/venv /home/myuser/venv
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/myuser/venv
ENV PATH="/home/myuser/venv/bin:$PATH"

CMD python3.11 /app/script_bot.py
```

This worked fine, and thus, i proceeded with creating a Dockerfile for a distroless build. The following is what i got.

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim AS builder-image

# avoid stuck build due to user prompt
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# create and activate virtual environment
# using final folder name to avoid path issues with packages
RUN python3.11 -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# install requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir wheel
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY /app /app
RUN chmod 755 /app && mkdir /files && chmod 744 /files

FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian12:nonroot AS runner-image

# Determine chipset architecture for copying python
ARG CHIPSET_ARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu

# required by lots of packages - e.g. six, numpy, wsgi
COPY --from=builder-image /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libz.so.1 /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/
# required by google-cloud/grpcio
COPY --from=builder-image /usr/lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libffi* /usr/lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/
COPY --from=builder-image /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libexpat* /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/

# Copy python from builder
COPY --from=builder-image /usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-image /usr/local/bin/python3.11 /usr/local/bin/python3.11
COPY --from=builder-image /etc/ld.so.cache /etc/ld.so.cache
COPY --from=builder-image /app /app
COPY --from=builder-image /files /files

WORKDIR /tmp
ENV APP_TMP_DATA=/tmp

# activate virtual environment
COPY --from=builder-image /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python3.11", "/app/script_bot.py"]
```

However, this returned an error: "exec /usr/local/bin/python3.11: no such file or directory" when the container is run.
I took [this article](https://luis-sena.medium.com/creating-the-perfect-python-dockerfile-51bdec41f1c8) as the guide in making the regular multi-stage python build, and [this article](https://alex-moss.medium.com/creating-an-up-to-date-python-distroless-container-image-e3da728d7a80) as the guide in making the distroless multi-stage python build.

I tried changing every python variable from python3.11 to python3 and python in the Dockerfile, but to no avail. I tried running `ls -l /usr/local/bin/` in a container running python:3.11.4-slim and got the following output.

```
total 48
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Aug 16 05:25 2to3 -> 2to3-3.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   102 Aug 16 05:25 2to3-3.11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     5 Aug 16 05:26 idle -> idle3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     8 Aug 16 05:25 idle3 -> idle3.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   100 Aug 16 05:25 idle3.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   226 Aug 16 05:26 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   226 Aug 16 05:26 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   226 Aug 16 05:26 pip3.11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     6 Aug 16 05:26 pydoc -> pydoc3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Aug 16 05:25 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    85 Aug 16 05:25 pydoc3.11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     7 Aug 16 05:26 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    14 Aug 16 05:26 python-config -> python3-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    10 Aug 16 05:25 python3 -> python3.11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    17 Aug 16 05:25 python3-config -> python3.11-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14472 Aug 16 05:25 python3.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3005 Aug 16 05:25 python3.11-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   213 Aug 16 05:26 wheel
```

In here we can see that `python` is symlinked to `python3`, which in turn is symlinked to `python3.11`, so i don't think the issue is with the name of the executable itself (please correct me if I'm wrong, though).
I tried using the docker image made by the author of the distroless python image article by using the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim AS builder-image

# avoid stuck build due to user prompt
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# create and activate virtual environment
# using final folder name to avoid path issues with packages
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# install requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -Ur requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /files

FROM al3xos/python-builder:3.10-debian11 AS runner-image

COPY --chmod=755 /app /app
COPY --from=builder-image --chmod=744 /files /files

WORKDIR /tmp
ENV APP_TMP_DATA=/tmp

# activate virtual environment
COPY --from=builder-image /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

CMD ["/app/script_bot.py"]
```

This, however returns an error "exec /app/script_bot.py: no such file or directory". I also tried activating the virtual env (which i also didn't do in my first multi-stage buld without distroless runner base image) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327097/elegant-python-distroless-docker-image-web-api), and the result is the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim AS builder-image

# avoid stuck build due to user prompt
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# create and activate virtual environment
# using final folder name to avoid path issues with packages
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# install requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -Ur requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /files

FROM al3xos/python-builder:3.10-debian11 AS runner-image

COPY --chmod=755 /app /app
COPY --from=builder-image --chmod=744 /files /files

WORKDIR /tmp
ENV APP_TMP_DATA=/tmp

# activate virtual environment
COPY --from=builder-image --chmod=755 /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN /opt/venv/bin/activate
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/python", "/app/script_bot.py"]
```

The resulting container returned a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy'" error when run. I then tried copying the author's [example](https://github.com/alexdmoss/distroless-python/blob/main/tests/pandas/Dockerfile) on a Dockerfile for a python code utilizing pandas and came up with the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


FROM al3xos/python-builder:3.10-debian11

COPY . /app
COPY --from=builder /home/monty/.local /home/monty/.local

ENV PYTHONPATH=/home/monty/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["script_bot.py"]
```

I don't understand how this or the example could actually work, and it gave me a "COPY failed: stat home/monty/.local: file does not exist" error. Was the example needed some other configuration not mentioned in the article?
As much as i want to use the distroless python image published on `gcr.io`, i can't really use it since it's still experimental and they don't recommend using it for production. By the way, I built the images using DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 and I'm creating a dockerized telegram bot, if that matters. Also, is the docker image published by the author of the (distroless multi-stage python build)[https://alex-moss.medium.com/creating-an-up-to-date-python-distroless-container-image-e3da728d7a80] likely to be more stable and/or secure than the python distroless docker image published by `gcr.io`?

Comment: I'm not clear this approach will work.  Python virtual environments tend to be tied to an _exact_ version and build of the Python interpreter, and that can have some significant dependencies (C shared libraries, the Python standard library, ...).  Your later examples where you build a Python 3.11 virtual environment and then try to run it on Python 3.10 seem likely to run into trouble.  What's wrong with the initial working Dockerfile?

Comment: @david-maze I think you are right about the version incompatibility. I probably should've built a Python 3.10 virtual env. There's nothing wrong with my initial Dockerfile per se. I simply wanted to implement a distroless approach in building the docker image, instead of a multi stage build using a the official python base image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, this returned an error: "exec /usr/local/bin/python3.11: no such file or directory"

When you know that the actual binary exists, this error typically means the kernel can't find the appropriate dynamic loader. If we boot into a `python:3.11.4-slim` image and run `ldd` to show dependencies, we see that `python3.11` requires:

```
root@686b3d1ca79b:/# ldd /usr/local/bin/python3.11
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc51f87000)
        libpython3.11.so.1.0 => /usr/local/bin/../lib/libpython3.11.so.1.0 (0x00007f92dc400000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f92dc21d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f92dc13e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f92dc92d000)
```

Your Dockerfile is failing to copy the dynamic loader (`ld-linux...`) as well as both `libc` and `libm`. If I add the following lines to your Dockerfile...

```
COPY --from=builder-image /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/
COPY --from=builder-image /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libc.so.6 /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/
COPY --from=builder-image /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libm.so.6 /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/
```

...then I am able to successfully start the Python interpreter.

---

The Dockerfile I used for testing looks like this (I've removed the parts relating to your application and I've added the above lines):

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim AS builder-image

# avoid stuck build due to user prompt
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# create and activate virtual environment
# using final folder name to avoid path issues with packages
RUN python3.11 -m venv /opt/venv

FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian12:nonroot AS runner-image

# Determine chipset architecture for copying python
ARG CHIPSET_ARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu

# required by lots of packages - e.g. six, numpy, wsgi
COPY --from=builder-image /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libz.so.1 /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/
# required by google-cloud/grpcio
COPY --from=builder-image /usr/lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libffi* /usr/lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/
COPY --from=builder-image /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libexpat* /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/

# Copy python from builder
COPY --from=builder-image /usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-image /usr/local/bin/python3.11 /usr/local/bin/python3.11
COPY --from=builder-image /etc/ld.so.cache /etc/ld.so.cache

# activate virtual environment
COPY --from=builder-image /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY --from=builder-image /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/
COPY --from=builder-image /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libc.so.6 /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/
COPY --from=builder-image /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/libm.so.6 /lib/${CHIPSET_ARCH}/
```

And running an image built from that Dockerfile looks like:

```
$ docker run -it --rm pythontest /usr/local/bin/python3.11
Python 3.11.4 (main, Aug 16 2023, 05:23:18) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: This solution seems to work. It also seems that i didn't copy all of the libraries that my imported python modules require. After following this solution and copying all of the required libraries, my dockerized telegram bot seems to be working fine. Thank you.